# JQuery Creating Dynamic and Leveled/Indented Lists of Elements

Tags: jquery, html, list, parent-child

I am trying to work on building a tool that allows our admins to create levels of keywords to then associate with their documents.  For example, a layout of keywords would look like this:

```
Level 2: NBA Teams
   Level 3: Eastern Conference
   Level 3: Western Conference
      Level 4: Oklahoma City Thunder
      Level 4: Memphis Grizzlies
```

Ect...  This should give you an idea.  I have a mock up pretty close but once Level 4 begins to be introduced, it seems sporadic whether or not the items are added into their correct nests.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrU5n/1/

I don't know really how else to describe the issue but take a moment and click around on the jsFiddle test to see the issues with level 4.  In some instance, it works smoothly but in others, it does not and I have yet to find the link to determine exactly what causes the level four keywords to be added to the wrong level 3 keywords.  In some instances, as well, if I add a level 4 keyword to a level 3 one, then add a new level 3 keyword, it doesn't add it to the bottom of the list but adds it above the level 4 keywords.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrapped the idea and redid it entirely after rethinking the logic a bit.  For anybody interested.

Here is a snippet:

```
var index_2 = 16;
$("#container").on('click','.addlevel2', function() {
    $(level2_div).insertAfter(".level2_main:last").find("input").attr("name","field_"+index_2).attr("id","field_"+index_2);
    index_2++;
    return false;
});
```

Here is a new jsfiddle showing a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/xJ94F/